# Flutter : add a space between title and subtitle in ListTile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I add a space between `title` and `subtitle` in `ListTile` ?

```dart
ListTile(
 title: Text(" xxxxxxxx"),
 subtitle: Text("From: to"),
),
```

Comment: there is a padding option in ListTile you can add space using padding

Comment: upvote also if my answer helped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can wrap your **Text** widget of `title` into **Padding** widget and pass `padding` `bottom` of your desired gap like below :

```
ListTile(
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15.0),
            child: Text("title"),
          ),
          subtitle: Text("Subtitle"),
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ListTile(
          title: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
            child:  Text(" xxxxxxxx"),,
          ),
          subtitle:Text("From: to"),
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can give height property, in the style of Text, add in the subtitle to add space between title and subtitle.

```
ListTile(
      title: Text("xxxxx", 
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                 ),   
      subtitle: Text("xxxxxx"
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, height: 2),
                ),
),
```